# How can i fire my javascript function when woocommerce order has been completed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce, eventtrigger

I have tested my functions, my script is loaded to the website and I have tested it with a alert on scroll and it works but I cant seem to fire my function that calls my web service when the WooCommerce order is being processed using the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'addMy_script', 10, 1 );
```

Im not sure what to do at the moment, **How can I fire my callApi function** using the hook displayed above?

Full code for reference:

Register script:

```
function load_Javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script('prefix_script_01', plugins_url('/Wp_callApi.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_Javascript');

//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addMy_script' );

function addMy_script() {
    wp_enqueue_scripts('Wp_callApi');
    add_action('init', 'CallApi');
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'addMy_script', 10, 1);
```

Javascript `callApi()` function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    CallApi();
});

function CallApi() {

    try {
        jQuery(function($) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                URL: "http://test.com/wsmain.asmx/myFunction",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg + "Event has fierd");
                }
            });
        })
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: side note my php code is in a plugin so its called from the plugin not functions.php

Comment: quick comment... i BELIEVE what you are trying to do is monitor a server-side hook/action from the client-side... in that case you would need the javascript to run in an interval loop... to repeatedly check the server for status update abd react accordingly... ie: `setInterval` (related: `setTimeout`)